# How to move first N elements to the end of the list for each list in the list of lists

Tags: list, prolog

Is there any way in Prolog how can I move first N elements from a list and put them at the end.
I wanna do this for each list in the list of lists. Example:

Input:

`move(3, [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1,2,3], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]], R)`

Result:

```
R = [[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3], [1,2,3], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 3, 4, 5]]
```

I have no idea, does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried working with a single list instead of list of lists? You can then map it to list of lists.

Comment: No, i didnt...
What are you talking about? I mean, can you show it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing the same operation on each element of the list-of-lists above, i.e., take first three elements and append them at the back. So if you can define the operation itself first then it will be easy to do it for a list of lists.

```
% If the predicate op/3 is already defined the you can easily define
% another one for a list the elements
op_for_lists([], _, []).
op_for_lists([X|Xs], N, [Y|Ys]) :-
    operation(X, N, Y), op_for_lists(Xs, N, Ys).
```

So if you take @coredump's answer and replace `operation` with `rotate_left` it will work.

You can also use `maplist/3` with lambdas from `yall` library as follows

```
op_for_lists(Xs, N, Ys) :-
  maplist({N}/[In, Out]>>operation(In, N, Out), Xs, Ys).
```

It is easier if the constant argument is at the start, then you can simply use

```
maplist(operation(N), Xs, Ys)
```

to get the result for list-of-lists

Answer (score 4):

If you execute the following query, `Left` and `Right` will be bound to two lists that, when concatenated together, result in `[1,2,3,4,5]`:

```
?- append(Left, Right, [1,2,3,4,5]).
```

The above query admits 6 solutions (`Left` being empty, the list `[1]`, the list `[1,2]`, etc.). You can constrain the query by saying that `Left` exactly has three elements:

```
?- length(Left, 3), append(Left, Right, [1,2,3,4,5]).
Left = [1, 2, 3]
Right = [4, 5]
```

This has only one solution.

The rotation consists in producing a list where the `Left` part is on the right of the `Right` list:

```
?- length(Left, 3), 
   append(Left, Right, [1,2,3,4,5]),
   append(Right, Left, Result).
Left = [1, 2, 3]
Right = [4, 5]
Result = [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
```

The first predicate you need to write is thus:

```
rotate_left(List, Offset, Rotated) :-
  length(Left, Offset),
  append(Left, Right, List),
  append(Right, Left, Rotated).
```

Then you can apply this predicate on a list of lists.

---

NB. you may consider using this version instead:

```
rotate_left(List, Offset, Rotated) :-
    append(Left, Right, List),
    length(Left, Offset),
    append(Right, Left, Rotated).
```

It is a bit better because it allows `Offset` to be variable:

```
[eclipse 2]: rotate_left([a, b, c, d], N, [c, d, a, b]).

N = 2
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 1, maybe more) ? ;

No (0.00s cpu)
```

With the original version, `length(Left, N)` has both its arguments variable, and it keeps producing answers with longer and longer lists.

Comment: circular permutation might be a bit of misnomer since we are not doing `Offset mod ListLength`.

Comment: maybe rotate_list then, or rotate_left

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach:

**First:** Extract the number of starting elements. Here M will work as a counter that will tell us when to stop when extracting the starting element. The 0 in the base case is the indication to stop.

```
 s3(0,Rest,[], Rest):-!.
s3(M,[H|T],[H|R], Rest):-
    M1 is M-1,
    s3(M1,T,R, Rest).
```

**Second:** We need to append Rest (J) [which contains the remaining elements of the list] and R (Q) [which contains the starting elements].

```
append(J,Q,L)
```

**Third:** Putting the code altogether.

```
s3(0,Rest,[], Rest):-!.
s3(M,[H|T],[H|R], Rest):-
    M1 is M-1,
    s3(M1,T,R, Rest).

q1(M,[H|T],L):-
    s3(M,[H|T],Q,J),
    append(J,Q,L).
```

**Example:**

```
?-q1(3,[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],L).
L = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 3, 4, 5]

?-q1(3,[1,2,3,4,5],L).
L = [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
```

Now you can from this point on write a predicate that can deal with each list separately and give you the solution.

Comment: This approach will not work if the initial list has duplicate elements itself. So instead you can just extend the s2 predicate to get the rest of the elements too. Take a look at https://gist.github.com/k3ut0i/f8ca3630ccf4360d37ba90099109dbdc. I just extended your `s2` to not Ignore the second argument in the base case. Now just `s3(N, ListIn, Head, Tail), append(Tail, Head, Ans)` will give you the solution.

Comment: This is really good. I am a newbie and I am basically challenging my self to see if I am capable of coming up with a solution. I've updated my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use partition/4 (in SWI Prolog):

```
test(O):-
    L = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1,2,3], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]],
    maplist(move(3),L,O).

greater(N,L,E):-
    nth1(I,L,E),I > N.

move(N,L,O):-
    partition(greater(N,L),L,LO,LP),
    append(LO,LP,O).

?- test(O).
O = [[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 3, 4, 5]]
```